# Eclipse Javascript Content Assist for Object Members

Tags: javascript, eclipse, type-hinting

I'm using Eclipse (Keplar SR2 Standard with Web Development Tools) to write some Javascript. I want to use Content Assist, ideally on all the variables I define, but specifically on members variables of object arrays that are passed as function parameters.

```
/**
 * @name TupleClass
 * @class My TupleClass
 * @description holds name and value
 * @param {String} name
 * @param {String|Number|Boolean} value
 */
var TupleClass = function(name, value) {
    this.name = name;
    this.value = value;
};

function makeTuples() {
    var tuples = new Array();
    tuples[0] = new TuppleClass("HairColor", "Brown");
    tuples[1] = new TuppleClass("EyeColor", "Green");

    iterateTupples(tupples);
}

/**
 * @param {TupleClass[]} tupples
 */
function iterateTupples(tupples) {
    for (var i = 0; i < tupples.length; i++) {
        var aTupple = tupples[i];
        console.log("name[" + aTupple.name +"] value[" + aTupple.value + "]");
    }
}
```

So in the last line of the above code when I type "aTupple(dot)" the code assist would come up and offer "name" and "value" options.

Does anyone know how to do the type hinting magic to make this happen?

Comment: I don't think that Eclipse's JavaScript content assist will parse the comments, so it can't really know what the types are :-/

Comment: Actually, it should, and this is practically a textbook supported case. @MindSpiker, it's in a JavaScript Project's Source Folder?

Comment: I can only guess there's a bug, since it's not working in Luna SR2, either.

Comment: Yes @nitind it's in a JavaScript Project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first your JavaScript code is wrong. You write your class and variables with 2 'p'. It must be :

```
function makeTuples() {
    var tuples = new Array();
    tuples[0] = new TupleClass("HairColor", "Brown");
    tuples[1] = new TupleClass("EyeColor", "Green");

    iterateTupples(tuples);
}
```

But even with this fix, JSDT is not able to retrieve name and value properties. I suggest you that you install [tern.java](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Installation-Update-Site) after that, completion will work :

[image]

Comment: Will try to ppay more attention to the double pps